# Can you tell how long logs are stored using Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using Kibana to search through logs stored in our ELK stack. We have about 30 index patterns. Is there a simple way to verify how long logs are stored for?

Comment: Can you explain your issue in a little bit more details? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Val I would like to know how I can determine how many days the logs will be stored in our ELK implementation before they are automatically deleted.

Comment: Do you have any lifecycle policy set up?

Comment: @Val I'm not sure, I'm a novice user of Kibana.  I was just wondering if it's possible to navigate the menus within Kibana and view whatever policy has been setup that shows how long messages are stored for.